# Cannot set password for redis sentinel 3.2

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I tried to set up redis sentinel to make it has high availability and support fail over.
I begin by setup the redis replication (1 master and 2 slaves in 3 ec2-instances)

And after that, i install redis-sentinel service for each instance.

However, when i tried to access redis-sentinal remotely (from my local machine)
It shows following message

> DENIED Redis is running in protected mode because protected mode is enabled, no bind address was specified, no authentication password is requested to clients....

So, i tried to set `requirepass` in `sentinel.conf`.
But after i run `redis-cli -h REDIS-IP -a PASSWORD -p SENTINEL_PORT INFO`

It shows following

> NOAUTH Authentication required.

Is there anyway i could connect to redis-sentinel remotely?

Please advise.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I'm running into the same issue with 3.2. The only option I have found so far is to disable protected mode by setting `bind 0.0.0.0` in the configuration file, but that opens up sentinel to anyone...not good.

Comment: Please check this issue https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3279 @nerdherd

Answer (score 0):

It will be fixed in the new release
https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3279